# Codeigniter Pagination Result Record Order

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i am working on a codeigniter project. I am displaying a record from the database to the user i have used pagination for this purpose i am showing 20 records per page. On the displaying page i have set a table column in which i have numbered the records first page shows 1-20 records, Second page shows records from 20-40 but the number column counter starts again from 1-20 instead of showing 21-40.

here is my controller record:

```
$config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = 'http://localhost:81/ebook/' . "index.php/main/index";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->book_data->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        $data["result"] = $this->book_data->get_data($config["per_page"], $page);

        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
```

Here is my View code:

```
<tbody>
                        <?php

                        $x=0;

                        foreach ($result as $row) {?>

                        <tr>
                            <td ><?php echo $x = $x+1; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->TITLE; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->AUTHOR; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->PUBLISHER; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->PAGES; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo $row->PATH; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><input id="button" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="View" name="submit"></a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <hr>
            </div>
                <div id="page" style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center">
                    <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: does get_data define an offset for the query? Typically I would get the required offset and pass it to the query function (along with the limit) to get the correct data set.

Comment: @xd6_ its not an offset for jquery

Answer (score 0):

of course it does - you're starting with $x = 0 each time.

pass your (per page value * (page num - 1) ) + 1

and you'll have it.

(you can also increment with $x++; instead of $x = $x + 1. does the same, looks more experienced ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

When you init the counter `$x`, you need consider `per_page` values.
So change `$x = 0` to this:

```
$x =  isset($_GET["per_page"]) ? $_GET["per_page"] : 0;
```

Also as @jmadsen mentioned, use `$x++` instead of `$x=$x+1`;

Answer (score 0):

pass $x some value from controller  e.g pass 1 as by default $x=value_from_controller_data_array when you are at page 1 and when next time you click on page 2 button just pass record_to_display_per_page * (page_number - 1) ) + 1 through link to your controller and when next time the view would be loaded with the desired result

Comment: @jmadsen if you think the answer is described well enough please vote up the answer

Comment: I was commenting on how you simply re-wrote the answers already given. No, I don't think it is good enough to upvote